# Problem with url

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 20;
xhr.open('GET','http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert/x);
```

How can i pass the value of x in the http string , so as to get

```
xhr.open('GET','http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert/20); as request?
```

Answer (score 1):

`xhr.open('GET','http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert/' + x);`

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
xhr.open('GET','http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert/' + x);
```

You need to concatenate the value of `x` to the URL string.

Answer (score 0):

```
xhr.open('GET','http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert/' + x);
```

You should use [JavaScript's + operator](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) to concatenate the Strings.